# How to configure(SSL) self signed certificate in Alfresco 6.2 test environment after docker based installation?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, alfresco, alfresco-share, self-signed-certificate

I have installed Alfresco 6.2 using docker based installation and it's working fine with http.
Now, I have to run same set-up on https and i have to apply self signed certificate for this.

Can someone please provide the steps to generate this self-signed certificate and how to apply it inside docker image.

Any help will be appreciated.

I already did same thing for Alfresco 5.2 without docker, but here I am quite new to docker and not understanding how to do this.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the tomcat certificate I would recommend to setup SSL on nginx or any other reverse proxy. The Tomcat certificate is also used to authenticate Solr. Configuration errors can easily cause the search to stop working.

When using a reverse proxy don't forget to set your external connection in alfresco-global.properties to avoid problems with the CSRF Token Filter. e.g.:

```
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=alfresco.mycompany.com
alfresco.port=443
alfresco.protocol=https

share.context=share
share.host=${alfresco.host}
share.port=${alfresco.port}
share.protocol=${alfresco.protocol}
```

Comment: Thanks @Heiko Robert for your answer. Can you please provide exact steps to set-up SSL on ngnix, So it will be helpful for many people in future including me. Also, after seting up SSL on ngnix, do we need any additional changes to make it applicable for Alfresco or only alfresco-golbal.properties changes will be enough?